# Drupal permissions page is blank white after adding new cck type

Tags: drupal

In Drupal after adding a new CCK type. I go to the admin/user/permissions page and its blank white? If i restore back to a early snapshot, one without the newly added cck type the permissions page works again. I have tried to disable page cache in the performance section but it did not help. I have about 100 installed modules, and 4 user Roles. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/nnsaweb/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 562.

Comment: I Enabled Error Reporting by adding the snippet on the index.php page. I still only saw a white screen. Note that 'Memory problems may still not be displayed'.
I deleted 1 cck type then added a new cck type. And my permissions page worked. But when I add 1 more cck type the permissions page goes blank white. I have only 36 cck types. if I add 1 more it blanks out the permissions page.

Comment: The Centos server etc/php.ini has the basic tweaks:
post_max to 200M
upload_max_filesize to 200M
max_execution_time = 1000
But 'realpath_cache_size' is commented out
I dont have permission to write to this file, but i think it should be:
realpath_cache_size=24M

Comment: The Centos server etc/my.cnf has nothing in it, see below:

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Answer (score 0):

What kind of CCK field?  Is it the only one of its kind?  Have you tried disabling the module that provides it?  If this fixes the problem, I would take a look at that module's issue queue and see if others are running into this.

Comment: Not a field, but a new cck type. I have 36 cck types. If I add one more the permissions page does not load, its white. I may try disabling one module at a time and re check.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal Devel module caused the permissions page load problem WSOD. Once I disabled it the page worked. I will only use this on our dev site for theme development from now on. Thanks for all of your advice.